# MAGMI config error

Tags: magento, magmi

I'm getting the following error when running MAGMI. I verified that username, dbname, passw, port, etc., are all correct. Any better idea of what I need to address? The log isn't of much help, just showing the login process completing, etc., and then later on showing this:

```
[SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error:
```

My first thought was username/pwd, but it's not.

Comment: What's the system error?

Comment: 111. Turns out I was trying to connect remotely instead of locally. Problem solved by pointing login to localhost instead of the domain.